# Subscription not working angular2

Tags: javascript, angular2-services

i have an angular2 program in which i want to update data of a component when a click is made on another component. i have made a service in which i have two methods one for updating data and other for getting data.

my service is as follows

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';


@Injectable()
export class DataserviceService {

    public subject = new Subject<any>();

    sendMessage(message: any) {
      debugger;
        this.subject.next({ text: message });
    }

    clearMessage() {
        this.subject.next();
    }

    getMessage(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject;
    }
}
```

in my component `a` where click is made. i have this function to update data.

```
onClick()
    {
       this._dataserviceService.sendMessage(this.getJsonData());
    }
```

and in component `b` i have subscribed it this way.

```
 ngOnInit() {
debugger;
     this.subscription = this._dataserviceService.getMessage().subscribe(message => { this.message = message;
     console.log(this.message)
     debugger;
    });
  }
```

if i do the subscription in same component it works fine but in other component it is not updating any data.
Any help would be appreciated.

**edit**
As of my understanding the main issue is that my subscriber component is loading after the service is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your getMessage() function by :

```
getMessage(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
}
```

It seems that as of right now, your getMessage() does not return an observable object, which would explain why the subscribe method in ineffective.

Comment: i have already tried that. Also subject class is child class of observable class and it does not matter if i parse it or not.

Comment: I have exactly the same code (different variables names but) in the angular app i'm working on right now and it seems to be working as intended... apologies if you have already done it, but have you checked that your service is properly set up in your app.js file (i.e. imported and added to the providers array) as well as being imported in the b component?

Comment: Looking back at your latest edit, I suspect that the problem is actually not in the sample you've posted